# Where can I find the Static IP for IP Based SSL Azure Web Apps?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webapps

Our company is working towards customers with very restricted internet access. The customers usually needs IP-addresses and ports to "whitelist", to allow the users in their network to communicate with our server (an Azure Web App). I would love to be corrected if I am wrong, but the way I have figured this to work is that I send them the range of Outbound IP Addresses from the Properties tab of the Web App in the Azure Portal.

We are now testing out a Static IP Address, [as suggested in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#get-a-static-inbound-ip), so that we only have to request 1 address to whitelist. We have a custom domain, and we have enabled IP Based SSL. But where can I get our static IP? I see one IP in the Custom Domain section, with a tooltip saying this is the one to use for DNS A Records. I also see a Virtual IP Address in Properties, along with the usual range of Inbound IP Addresses (and Additional Inbound IP Addresses).

Comment: you can refer this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-inbound-outbound-ips#get-a-static-inbound-ip) about getting static inbound IP, this is also from the documentation which you've shared. Also check this [QnA](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d09dc54-8332-47af-bbc0-ac8f96465200/azure-app-service-web-app-and-static-ip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the static Inbound IP you need to setup the secure custom domain.
You can follow below steps to get it done:

1. select **App Services** >  **app-name**
2. From the left pane selecting  **Custom domains**  >  **Add binding**
3. And selecting  **TLS/SSL settings**  >  **Add TLS/SSL binding**

[image]

4. Add the binding in a custom domain.
5. Add a certificate for custom domain - Here you can [import app service certificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-certificate#import-an-app-service-certificate)

Refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-ssl-bindings#secure-a-custom-domain) for more insights

Comment: I have done all this. Where in the portal can I get the static IP to use after all these steps?

Comment: I have contacted Microsoft, and they have confirmed that the IP address in Customn Domains, like in the screenshot (13.69.68.6) is the one that becomes the static IP. This IP also appears in Virtual IP in the Properties section. My confusion was only that the docs did not verify this, and I didn't wanna request whitelisting of the wrong IP.